# Mongoose pagination with first item instead of skip

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I'm trying to do pagination on a list of items, and I thought I'd get away with skip and limit, but it turns out that's not the case. When I'm sorting say Instagram images in descending order of likes, if there was a new image inserted at position zero since I looked at the last page, my page will be off by one, and it will return one of the items already returned on the last page. What I'm trying to do is similar to how the Instagram api works, where there is a "min_tag_id" parameter, but I don't know if this is possible with mongodb alone in one query. What I'm doing right now is querying all entries and slice my needed array with javascript. So I'd like to skip to a specific item and limit my results from there.

Another kind of working solution would be if I could do a quick query returning only the position (index) of a document in a given query, so i could use that in the next query as the skip amount.

Comment: I don't have a session to store the last requested id in. All requests are anonymous. Though I suppose that's one way to do it.

Comment: Well if you are talking about remote requests then you are going to need some form of persistence to tie to the request. Therefore, that is what sessions do. The general principles outlaid are "store somewhere" the relevant "seen" information to facilitate filtering the ordered results.

Comment: It also just occurred to be that you might be confusing "sessions" with "authentication". There is nothing about session data that requires someone to provide credentials and authenticate. There would be very few websites that do not employ session data. And you you are someone who blocks cookies, then I change your URL to include the session information. Or you loose features. Because I'm mean like that.

Comment: Okay, yeah. I realized that since the list ordered by likes is constantly changing, normal pagination is not appropriate even if I have the last item. So yeah, I can't really get around saving which items the user has seen already. Thanks.

Comment: Well that basically is the concept. And remember that you only need to save the "seen" items since the last sort order change. So it's either that or go building massive cached lists by possible sorts. Just like instagram would do.